# Record video without sound recording with default video intent ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE or Remove sound after video record like snap chat

Tags: android, android-video-record

I want to record a video with mute state with default video recording intent which is `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`

I am trying following code for mute purpose but it is not working

```
private void setMicMuted(boolean state){
    AudioManager myAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    // get the working mode and keep it
    int workingAudioMode = myAudioManager.getMode();

    myAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

    // change mic state only if needed
    if (myAudioManager.isMicrophoneMute() != state) {
        myAudioManager.setMicrophoneMute(state);
    }

    // set back the original working mode
    myAudioManager.setMode(workingAudioMode);
}
```

Any idea about that or any 3rd party library or demo available for this ?

or I have second option like I remove sound after the record the video like the snap chat. It is possible or not ? Or Can I achieve same functionality like snap chat or not ?

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" permission is necessary to change audio settings. so first declare below permission in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Your code is also working fine and can record video without sound with the default video capture intent but still i'm posting the whole activity code below:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnRecord;
    int REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_VIDEO = 201;
    private final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FOR_VIDEO = 202;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
        btnRecord = findViewById(R.id.btnRecord);
        btnRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                                        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                        android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                                        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                                },
                                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FOR_VIDEO);

                    } else {
                        takeVideo();
                    }

                } else {
                    takeVideo();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FOR_VIDEO: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    takeVideo();

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permissions Declined! Can't record video withon permissions. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }


    private void takeVideo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 3000);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_VIDEO);
        setMicMuted(true);
    }

    private void setMicMuted(Boolean state){
//        AudioManager myAudioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        AudioManager myAudioManager = (AudioManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        // get the working mode and keep it
        int workingAudioMode = myAudioManager.getMode();

        myAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

        // change mic state only if needed
        if (myAudioManager.isMicrophoneMute() != state) {
            myAudioManager.setMicrophoneMute(state);
        }

        // set back the original working mode
        myAudioManager.setMode(workingAudioMode);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try{
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_VIDEO) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri videoUri = data.getData();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved to:\n" +
                            videoUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Video recording cancelled.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to record video",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Unexpected error", "@video recording " + e.toString());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes Right. I already achieve this. But check my question again I want to second option. Any about that ?

Comment: FFMPEG can remove audio from the recorded video and generate new video file. so you have implement ffmpeg for android. just try to search "how to integrate ffmpeg library in android". and after integrating library in your android project, there are several commnads which can do it for you and generate new file

Comment: I found this https://github.com/amosyuen/FFmpegVideoRecorder . But no audio remove option or command is there.

Comment: you have to build it by yourself. here is the most useful link i found for ffmpeg commands with android: "https://superuser.com/questions/1089184/how-can-i-using-code-in-android-ffmpeg-library".  Also let me clear you that there will be ffmpeg bash or exe file which will reside in many project directory with different cpu architectures such as armabi, armabi-v7 etc and after loading that file with java code you can be able to fire ffmpeg commands with anrdoid and can generate new video file. you have to search for that because ffmpeg is a huge topic.

Comment: Yes. Thanks you. If any direct library found by you than please post here.

Comment: This is the most useful link that i have found "https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android" which provides us to execute ffmpeg commands as i said

Answer (score 1):

This code is working but can you show me what you sending for boolean state in main activity??

```
 private void setMicMuted(Boolean state){
//        AudioManager myAudioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        AudioManager myAudioManager = (AudioManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        // get the working mode and keep it
        int workingAudioMode = myAudioManager.getMode();

        myAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

        // change mic state only if needed
        if (myAudioManager.isMicrophoneMute() != state) {
            myAudioManager.setMicrophoneMute(state);
        }

        // set back the original working mode
        myAudioManager.setMode(workingAudioMode);
    }
```

It is you code bro...